# Why this padding is different even with the same value? Flutter

Tags: flutter

*Output of code

[image]

*Output of code

[image]

This is my custom widget which takes images.

```
Widget customcategories({@required String image, @required String name}){
return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    height: 70.0,
                    width: 70.0,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(image),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 2.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(name),
                  ),
                ],
              );
  }
```

Here I have given same padding from right side of 4.0 between all widgets. First widget gets left side padding too not touch the device screen. Here after 4 widgets padding in output is bigger than I gave (4.0)(look image for output result) and its still bigger even if I remove the padding. Why this is happening? And how to solve it??
given the source code below :

```
Container( 
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant1.png",
                    name: "All"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant2.png",
                    name: "Flower"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant3.png",
                    name: "Plant"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant4.png",
                    name: "Tree"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant1.png",
                    name: "Decoration"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant2.png",
                    name: "Bonsai"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant3.png",
                    name: "Medic"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0)),
                  customcategories(
                    image: "assets/images/plant4.png",
                    name: "Fregerence"
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: But why padding is different in some widgets not all?? Or you are saying that my image's sizes are different??? If  Yes then why issue still remains when I have wrapped my images in a container and container have its size. Image should be resize automatically according container size!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem found for your categories name, lets try out

```
Widget customcategories({@required String image, @required String name}){
return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    height: 70.0,
                    width: 70.0,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(image),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 2.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 65
                    child: Text(name),
                  ),
                ],
              );
  }
```

Comment: Ohh Yess!!! name contains different character length so it was taking their padding (i gave them lol) 
What a tiny but hard to figure out problem! (at least for beginners like me). Thanks man I appreciate it :)